# Angular 2 : obtain currency value depending on where you are

Tags: angular, currency, angular-pipe

I use `{{listing.sellPrice | currency : undefined : 0}}` and it makes `$` only.
I want for example if a person is in Europe, his currency would be affected in `€`. A user in China could see his currency in `¥` (Yuan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually using the pipe with `currencyCode = undefined` because of the first parameter in

```
{{listing.sellPrice | currency : undefined : 0}}
```

So it always defaults to USD.

As explained [in the docs](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe)
You will need to specifically give in the currencyCode (ISO standard) you want to use.

```
{{listing.sellPrice | currency : currencyCode : 0}}
```

Then you could have the value `currencyCode` be selected by the user.

AFAIK there's no standard way to obtain this code from a person's location. You can use some additional tool if you want like https://www.npmjs.com/package/locale-currency

Comment: Thank you first for the answer. But I wanted to know if I could have a currencyCode assigned immediately based on the zone. Is it possible ?

Comment: take a look at https://hackernoon.com/easily-getting-a-users-country-currency-timezone-or-language-from-their-ip-address-5124ea4bba0e